# run python file in browser

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

i have a python file that when runned outputs a window with a [3d interactive rubik's cube](https://github.com/davidwhogg/MagicCube), so far so good. I need to run that file inside a browser so the output is in a div

Comment: You cannot run Python inside a browser.  You can run Python on a server that is being accessed by a browser, but that wouldn't work very well in this case - the best you could hope for would basically be a slideshow, you couldn't get the smooth interactivity of manipulating the cube locally.  The best approach to getting something like this actually working in a browser would probably be WebGL with JavaScript - it looks like there are hundreds of WebGL Rubik's Cubes online to get you started.

Comment: i'm kind of restricted only to python, the cube must be based on python, how can i run it on a server